# Converting hours to HH:MM format

Tags: zapier

I need to insert the duration of a task into Pipedrive in the format HH:MM.
I have made a small Java script using code in zapier to find the difference between start og end time and thereby find number of hours or minutes that is the duration. 
But I don't know how to convert this into HH:MM using JavaScript. Any suggestions?
Thanks
Steve

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Hey I assume you are trying to get Calendly working with Pipedrive. I have same issue. Did you figured it out? I would be grateful for reply!

Answer (score 0):

What is the unit of measurement for the duration that you have?
If it's in minutes, you can use the below code as reference to convert minutes into HH:MM format.
The duration_minutes variable refers to a variable that holds the initial duration that you calculated.

```
//Calculate hours and minutes from the variable holding the duration
var hours = Math.floor(duration_minutes/60)
var minutes = duration_minutes%60

//Hours less than 10 need a prefix of 0
if (hours < 10){
    hours = 0 + hours.toString();
}
else{
    hours = hours.toString();
}

//Minutes less than 10 need a prefix of 0
if (minutes < 10){
    minutes = 0 + minutes.toString();
}
else{
    minutes = minutes.toString();
}

//Join hours and minutes together to make HH:MM format
var fullduration = hours + ":" + minutes;
```

If duration_minutes is 150, fullduration will become 02:30.